# Regular Expression

Tags: powershell

I need to extract few values from below string with Powershell Regex.

```
Request ID = 1234 { andquot;EMOandquot;: andquot;123456-Uandquot;, andquot;Terminated Accountandquot;: andquot;Test Userandquot;, andquot;Descriptionandquot;: andquot;andquot;, andquot;Last Dayandquot;: andquot;2019-06-26andquot;, andquot;Terminated User Mailandquot;: andquot;Test.User@gmail.comandquot; } Location : UK ,London
```

I Need to get Test.User@gmail.com, Test User and 2019-06-26.  Please help me to get powershell regex for getting these values from above string.

Thank you.

I Tried below -

$description = "Request ID = 1234 { andquot;EMOandquot;: andquot;123456-Uandquot;, andquot;Terminated Accountandquot;: andquot;Test Userandquot;, andquot;Descriptionandquot;: andquot;andquot;, andquot;Last Dayandquot;: andquot;2019-06-26andquot;, andquot;Terminated User Mailandquot;: andquot;Test.User@gmail.comandquot; } Location : UK ,London"

$formatdesc = $description -replace ' ?(and)?quot;','"'

$formatdesc
Request ID = 1234 {"EMO":"123456-U","Terminated Account":"Test User","Description":"","Last Day":"2019-06-26","Terminated User Mail":"Test.User@gmail.com" } Location : UK ,London

With above how would  I have extract Terminated User Mail, Terminated Account and Last Day the values are not static they are dynamic. Please help.

Comment: Please show a modicum of effort.  Thank you.

Comment: Tried some  pattern matches as below for email did not help though -"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})

Comment: Tried  -split with : as deliminator not  sure how to position. Please  help

Comment: @gows Please update your answer to include everything you have tried :)

Comment: I'd start by restoring the quotes with something like `$string -replace ' ?(and)?quot;','"'`

Answer (score 1):

Break down the pattern logically you are looking to find first. It looks like you are looking for: Test.User@gmail.com Test User - use a simple -match e.g. $Myvariablename = [Your string] -match 'Test.User@gmail.com'

2019-06-26: For a date like this, break it down to its parts so that's 4 digits, a hyphen, 2 digits, a hyphen and then 2 digits so that (quickly and therefore not perfect without testing) comes out to a -match like $Myvariablename = [Your string] -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

Comment: This is more than enough info for you to build the script you need